# How to access the node-orm2 Express middleware inside passport.deserializeUser

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js, middleware, node-orm2

I'm using [Passport](http://passportjs.org/) for authentication in conjunction with [node-orm2](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2). Passport requires you to register functions for serializing and deserializing users to and from the session. My users are stored in a database which I'm accessing through node-orm2's Express middleware. The orm2 middleware tags its models onto the req object for easy access. Unfortunately, Passport does not provide access to the req object in `deserializeUser`. I've come across this [solution](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/111), but am hoping for something better:

```
var User;

passport.use({ passReqToCallback: true }, new LocalStrategy(function (request, username, password, done) {
    if (!User) {
        User = request.models.User;
    }

User
    .find({ username: username })
    .limit(1)
    .run(function (err, users) {
        var user = users[0];

        if (err) {
            done(err);
        } else if (!hasher.verify(password, user.password)) {
            done(null, false);
        } else {
            done(null, user);
        }
    });
}));

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    User.get(id, done);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

req will be passed to passport's serialize and deserialize callbacks in the upcoming release, 0.2.0: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/pull/160